# fill dataframe multiprocessing

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, multiprocessing, dataframe

I'm working on a model that must perform a lot of linear regressions, it is a forecast model and its index is a date.  To minimize the running time, I tried with multiprocessing module in python.  The script runs fine and runs over all the cpu's, but I can't save the data into the same dataframe, the script overwrites the dataframe and don't save all the calculations, each loop must fill a dataframe's column.  I tried to use global variables, but it didn't work.  I appreciate too much your help.

When I run the script without multiprocessing it works fine and the data are saved succesfully.

The error is 'global name 'df_pronostico' is not defined'.

Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import itertools as itools
import math
import progressbar
import functools
import multiprocessing as mp


def rezago_isopercentiles(isopercentiles, rezago):
    nuevo_indice = (isopercentiles.index + -rezago)
    indice_final = nuevo_indice[nuevo_indice > 0]
    indice_inicial = nuevo_indice[nuevo_indice < 1] + 12
    nuevo_indice = indice_inicial.append(indice_final)
    isopercentiles = isopercentiles.reindex(index=nuevo_indice)
    isopercentiles.reset_index()
    return isopercentiles


def predictores(archivo_series, rango_modelo, estaciones): # archivo_series ExcelFile, rango_modelo date_range, estaciones rango con estaciones
    sxls_predictores = pd.ExcelWriter(path='matriz_predictores.xlsx')
    df_alias = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(estaciones)), columns=['estacion', 'alias'])
    for i in range(len(estaciones)):
        df_alias.iloc[i]['estacion'] = float(estaciones[i])
        df_alias.iloc[i]['alias'] = 'X' + str(i + 1)
    print df_alias.to_string()

    df_ql = archivo_series.parse(sheetname='QL', index_col='Fecha')
    df_pt = archivo_series.parse(sheetname='PT', index_col='Fecha')
    serie_ql = df_ql.columns[0]
    df_predictores_total = pd.DataFrame(index=rango_modelo, dtype='float')

    for estacion in df_alias.index:
        for i in range(1, 13):
            nombre = df_alias.loc[estacion]['alias'] + 'R' + str(i)
            df_predictores_total[nombre] = df_pt[df_alias.loc[float(estacion)]['estacion']].shift(i)

    for i in range(1, 13):
        df_predictores_total['Q1R' + str(i)] = df_ql[serie_ql].shift(i)

    df_predictores_total.to_excel(excel_writer=sxls_predictores, sheet_name='PREDICTORES')
    df_alias.to_excel(excel_writer=sxls_predictores, sheet_name='ALIAS')
    sxls_predictores.save()
    return df_predictores_total


def fn_informatividad(completa, y, rango_modelo):

    inicio = 1
    fin = 5
    n = len(completa.columns)
    calculos = 0
    for k in range(inicio, fin):
        calculos += math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(k) * math.factorial(n - k))
    nom_archivo = 'urra_informatividad_' + str(inicio) + '_' + str(fin - 1) + '.xlsx'
    sxls_pronostico = pd.ExcelWriter(nom_archivo)
    print '\nCalculos proceso: ', calculos, '\nARchivo: ', nom_archivo

    widgets = [progressbar.Bar('>'), ' ', progressbar.ETA(), ' ', progressbar.ReverseBar('<')]
    pbar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=calculos).start()

    completa = completa.loc[rango_modelo]
    y = y.loc[rango_modelo]
    j = 0
    df_resumen = pd.DataFrame(index=range(calculos), columns=['modelo', 'variables', 'n', 'I'])
    for i in range(inicio - 1, fin - 1):
        for variables in itools.combinations(iterable=completa.columns, r=(i + 1)):
            x = completa[list(variables)]
            nombre = 'PR_' + str(j)
            df_resumen.iloc[j]['modelo'] = nombre
            df_resumen.iloc[j]['variables'] = str(variables)
            # df_resumen.iloc[j]['I'] = 0.5 * math.log(np.linalg.det(x.corr()) / np.linalg.det(pd.concat([y, x], axis=1).corr()))
            df_resumen.iloc[j]['I'] = 0.5 * math.log(1 / (1 - sm.OLS(y, x).fit().rsquared))
            df_resumen.iloc[j]['n'] = len(variables)
            j += 1
            pbar.update(j)
    df_resumen.to_excel(excel_writer=sxls_pronostico, sheet_name='Informatividad')
    sxls_pronostico.save()


def fn_nombremodelo(variables):
    nombre = ''
    for predictor in variables:
        nombre = nombre + predictor
    return nombre


def fn_nucleo_clao(variables, df_predictores_rezagos, df_isopercentiles, rango_entrenamiento,
                   ventana_entrenamiento, horizonte_pronostico, df_afluencias, estacion_QL):

    global df_pronostico, df_resumen, calculos, pbar

    nom_modelo = fn_nombremodelo(variables)
    df_predictores = pd.concat([df_isopercentiles, df_predictores_rezagos[list(variables)]], axis=1)
    df_predictores['const'] = 1
    df_informatividad = pd.DataFrame(index=rango_entrenamiento, columns=['Informatividad', 'R2'], dtype='float')
    for fecha in rango_entrenamiento:
        rango_ventana_entrenamiento = pd.date_range(start=fecha, periods=ventana_entrenamiento, freq='MS', name='Fecha')
        fecha_pronostico = fecha + pd.DateOffset(months=(ventana_entrenamiento + horizonte_pronostico - 1))
        y = df_afluencias.loc[rango_ventana_entrenamiento][float(estacion_QL)]
        x = df_predictores.loc[rango_ventana_entrenamiento]
        modelo = sm.OLS(y, x)
        results = modelo.fit()
        df_informatividad.loc[fecha]['Informatividad'] = 0.5 * math.log(1 / (1 - results.rsquared))
        df_informatividad.loc[fecha]['R2'] = results.rsquared
        xcal = df_predictores.loc[fecha_pronostico]
        if (xcal * results.params).sum() >= 0:
            df_pronostico.loc[fecha_pronostico][nom_modelo] = (xcal * results.params).sum()
        else:
            df_pronostico.loc[fecha_pronostico][nom_modelo] = 0
    df_resumen.loc[nom_modelo]['I'] = df_informatividad['Informatividad'].mean()
    df_resumen.loc[nom_modelo]['Var'] = df_informatividad['Informatividad'].var()
    df_resumen.loc[nom_modelo]['R2'] = df_informatividad['R2'].mean()
    j = calculos - pd.isnull(df_pronostico.loc[fecha - pd.DateOffset(months=-horizonte_pronostico)])[pd.isnull(df_pronostico.loc[fecha - pd.DateOffset(months=-horizonte_pronostico)]) == True].count()
    pbar.update(j)


def fn_clao(fin, inicio, calculos, df_predictores_rezagos, df_isopercentiles, rango_entrenamiento, ventana_entrenamiento, horizonte_pronostico, df_afluencias, estacion_QL):

    global df_pronostico, df_resumen, pbar

    widgets = [progressbar.Bar('>'), ' ', progressbar.ETA(), ' ', progressbar.ReverseBar('<')]
    pbar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval= calculos).start()

    resultado = []

    for i in range(inicio - 1, fin - 1): # range(len(df_predictores_rezagos.columns)):
        print '\nCombinando ', i + 1,  ' variable(s)...'
        pool = mp.Pool()
        parcial_clao = functools.partial(fn_nucleo_clao, df_predictores_rezagos=df_predictores_rezagos,
                       df_isopercentiles=df_isopercentiles, rango_entrenamiento=rango_entrenamiento,
                       ventana_entrenamiento=ventana_entrenamiento, horizonte_pronostico=horizonte_pronostico,
                       df_afluencias=df_afluencias, estacion_QL=estacion_QL)
        resultado.append(pool.map(parcial_clao, list(itools.combinations(df_predictores_rezagos.columns, i + 1))))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    pbar.finish()
    return resultado


def main():

    global df_pronostico, df_resumen, calculos

    oxls_series = pd.ExcelFile('urra_series.xlsx')
    oxls_isoper_QL = pd.ExcelFile('urra_QL_isopercentiles.xlsx')

    estacion_QL = '13037010'  # codigo de la estacion de caudal
    ventana_entrenamiento = 24  # tamano de la ventana en meses
    horizonte_pronostico = 1
    rezago_iso = 0
    inicio_rango_modelo = pd.datetime(1981, 1, 1)  # fecha inicio del pronostico
    fin_rango_modelo = pd.datetime(2012, 12, 1)  # fecha fin del pronostico
    rango_modelo = pd.date_range(start=inicio_rango_modelo, end=fin_rango_modelo, freq='MS', name='Fecha')

    estaciones_pt = ['13040010']

    df_predictores_rezagos = predictores(oxls_series, rango_modelo, estaciones_pt)
    df_afluencias = oxls_series.parse(sheetname='QL', index_col='Fecha').shift(-(horizonte_pronostico - 1))
    df_isoper_QL_12 = oxls_isoper_QL.parse(sheetname=estacion_QL, index_col='Mes')
    df_isoper_rezago = rezago_isopercentiles(df_isoper_QL_12, rezago_iso)
    df_isopercentiles = pd.DataFrame(index=rango_modelo, columns=list(df_isoper_rezago.columns), dtype='float')

    for fecha in rango_modelo:
        df_isopercentiles.loc[fecha] = df_isoper_rezago.loc[fecha.month]

    rango_entrenamiento = rango_modelo[:-(horizonte_pronostico + ventana_entrenamiento - 1)]
    rango_pronostico = rango_modelo[ventana_entrenamiento:]

    calculos = 0
    n = len(df_predictores_rezagos.columns)
    for i in range(n):
        calculos = calculos + math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(i) * math.factorial(n - i))

    print '\nNumero de posibles predictores: ', n

    inicio = 1
    fin = 2
    n = len(df_predictores_rezagos.columns)
    calculos = 0
    for k in range(inicio, fin):
        calculos += math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(k) * math.factorial(n - k))
    nom_archivo = 'urra_pronostico_regresion_T' + str(horizonte_pronostico) + '_' + str(inicio) + '_' + str(fin - 1) +  '.xlsx'
    sxls_pronostico = pd.ExcelWriter(nom_archivo)
    print '\nCalculos proceso: ', calculos, '\nArchivo: ', nom_archivo

    columnas = []
    for i in range(inicio - 1, fin - 1):
        columnas.extend(list(itools.combinations(df_predictores_rezagos.columns, i + 1)))

    indice_resumen = ["" for x in range(len(columnas))]
    for i in range(len(columnas)):
        indice_resumen[i] = fn_nombremodelo(columnas[i])

    df_resumen = pd.DataFrame(index=indice_resumen, columns=['I', 'R2', 'Var'])
    df_pronostico = pd.DataFrame(index=rango_pronostico, columns=indice_resumen, dtype=float)
    df_pronostico[0] = df_afluencias[float(estacion_QL)]

    fn_clao(fin=fin, inicio=inicio, calculos=calculos, df_predictores_rezagos=df_predictores_rezagos,
            df_isopercentiles=df_isopercentiles, rango_entrenamiento=rango_entrenamiento,
            ventana_entrenamiento=ventana_entrenamiento, horizonte_pronostico=horizonte_pronostico,
            df_afluencias=df_afluencias, estacion_QL=estacion_QL)
```

Comment: Can you store the results from each processes separately (on disk or whatever) and then combine them once every process has finished?

Comment: In addition, you seem to be doing a lot of looping, and chained assignment (see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)), so you might want to make sure that what you are solving is efficient.